# e-shop Where will the pictures of a product be stored in a folder or database table

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to build an eshop website with pictures of the products. Where will the pictures be stored in a folder or database. If the user clicks on a thumnail I want to show several pictures of that product. Should i have a database table called images and put all the pictures connected to the product in that table?

How do the profissional websites do?

I will be using mvc and mssql server.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Store the Pictures in a folder and their path in the database.

Comment: Should I give the folder name the product id or the product name? The specification of the product should i store it in seperate table?

Comment: @user1498441 These are really design choices - there's no right and wrong answers here. SO is for solving programming issues, not general practice advice...